Influx of Trezor questions
TL;DR: 
Please mark Trezor's "customer support" questions as off-topic. We don't care whether packages have been sent, how to apply for a refund or whom to talk to regarding faulty hardware.
Please help provide canonical answers to topics of more general interest such as hierarchical deterministic key derivation, how wallets/addresses/transactions work, or how to recover coins sent to an address of another currency. As usually, please close as duplicates if a new question already has a comprehensive answer on our site.

We've been having a huge influx of Trezor related questions lately. Some of them are interesting, a bunch of them off-topic unfortunately. I would like to explain how that came to pass, how we can perhaps improve the situation.
As you may have read already, I'm trying to push for more users on Bitcoin.SE in order to get the site to graduate. I've been spurred to do that because 1. I think that Bitcoin.SE has the potential to be the go-to Q&A site for cryptocurrencies, 2. a SE site can disencumber experts by being much more time effective in providing easily retrievable information, 3. Ethereum recently graduated and I'd like us to follow suit, and because 4. it's frustrating to me that I'm doing about 350+ reviews per month and we still have a backlog— I'm hoping a bigger active community would help with that.
To that end, I've been trying to get in touch with a number of people from the Bitcoin community suggesting that they take ownership of tags related to their project. My idea here is that we don't need the experts necessarily to maintain the site, but that answers provided by them  on their topics specifically will make the site more valuable to users that have more time to do the maintenance work, and the community in general.
Anyway, I had been chatting a bit with a developer from Trezor. I showed him that there were a few unanswered questions about Trezor on our site, pointing out that they could perhaps have a look.
As Bitcoin.StackExchange.com shows up pretty early in search results (other than reddit where they answer community questions) I told him that it would probably be beneficial to them and the Bitcoin community if they wrote some good answers to the Trezor questions here. 
Obviously, we were in agreement that the Bitcoin.SE community has no insight into customer support topics, and that only technical questions were on topic. What I meant was, HD key derivation, questions about the security, or perhaps about the open source software they are using. What might not have been completely clear is whether questions such as how to recover a wallet or how to use certain features of the Trezor would be on-topic. I think they could be, but it would help a lot if some Trezor experts came in to provide the respective answers, so that we could close duplicates towards these canonical Q&A pairs. Generally, we can only answer questions that aim for public knowledge. 
So, what I thought was that we would be handling questions about Trezor much like we will answer questions about e.g. Bitcoin Core, Blockchain.info, Coinbase, MultiBit, or Mycelium when they come up.
Anyway, apparently someone from Trezor linked to Bitcoin.SE with the link titled "Ask the Experts". I'm trying to get in touch with them about better communicating that their customer support questions will not get an answer here, but so far I've been unable to reach my contact again.

I understand your frustration. We don't have the capacity to educate people what kind of questions should be asked on which forum (they are not really good at reading text tbh), therefore we removed the Bitcoin.SE link from our site completely.

@PavolRusnak: Thank you for your understanding.

I am the contact from Trezor team you mention in the text.
Just to offer an explanation:

Right now, we have a huge influx of new users, overwhelming our user support.
I noticed this post, which lead me to think it would be a good idea to link the users from our support page to Stack Exchange:


it would ease the load for our user support
it would move the questions to more easily discoverable place
our user support team could answer the questions, since they would have more time for it
it would make this SE more active

It seemed like a win-win for both us and this SE
However, linking of this site to the user support page did not significantly eased the load to our user support, so we couldn't spend the time answering question, plus it flooded this SE with crap questions 

So the experiment turned out badly. I will still try to help with Trezor questions when I have time, but we really can't help with our customer support right now, sorry.

Yeah, sorry about how it turned out. Maybe we can try again later, when we're both better prepared for it. :) I assume that there are currently lots of people getting Hardware wallets because of the BS debate?

I am not entirely sure why, but there is a lot of new people buying HW wallets, which started with the recent price rally but never stopped after the rally stopped. The people asking question are usually people that have no clue about the BS debate, they are confused by even the facts that the bitcoin price actually moves up/down, etc.

Some of the popular newbie guides must be advising to get a hardware wallet or something.
